# Dynamic form blazor

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor-server-side

I have the data stored in a JSON file, which I transfer to the page and display in a table. The table updates itself, so when I add a value to the "Class" property, it automatically updates. However, it adds 0 to the existing data for that value, but that's not the issue I want to address.
I want to automate the creation of input fields, meaning when I add a new value to the "Class," I want it to create a new input field for the user on the page. I've tried several approaches, but unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet.

```
<EditForm Model="novDelavec" OnValidSubmit="DodajDelavca">
    @foreach (var property in typeof(Delavec).GetProperties())
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="@property.Name">@property.Name</label>
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
            <InputText id="@property.Name" @bind-Value="property.GetValue(novDelavec)?.ToString()" class="form-control" />
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            {
            <InputNumber id="@property.Name" @bind-Value="Convert.ToInt32(property.GetValue(novDelavec))" class="form-control" />
            }
            // Dodajte še druge pogoje za druge tipe, če je potrebno
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit">Dodaj</button>
</EditForm>
@code {
    private List<Delavec> delavci;
    private Delavec novDelavec = new Delavec();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        delavci = await storitevDelavci.PridobiDelavceAsync();
    }

    private async Task DodajDelavca()
    {
        // Tukaj dodajte logiko za shranjevanje novega delavca v podatkovno zbirko ali seznam.
        // Po shranjevanju osvežite seznam `delavci` ali dodajte `novDelavec` v seznam.
        delavci.Add(novDelavec);
        novDelavec = new Delavec(); // Ponastavi novDelavec, da so vnosna polja ponastavljena.
    }
}
```

Table is working well:

```
@if (delavci == null)
{
    <p><em>Nalaganje...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var property in typeof(Delavec).GetProperties())
                {
                    <th>@property.Name</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var delavec in delavci)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var property in typeof(Delavec).GetProperties())
                    {
                        <td>@property.GetValue(delavec)</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

I have a problem with creating dynamic input fields. I'm working only on an example, so I know that the approach to accessing and saving data is not correct.

Comment: `@bind-Value` is *two-way* binding, but that will fail writing to that expression. Try the "long hand" version, with `Value` and especially `ValueChanged`